# Exporting Local Stored DB to readable file using SQFlite in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sqflite

I created Flutter App(Without APIs) only using Local storage SQFlite. Now I want to take backup of DB every month with human readable format. Is it possible to export Whole Database file.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform a data to needed format from app without converting DB (export all entities from DB and write it (with your corrections) to file). On Android side it is possible to access a .db file and export it to the user's storage.

Comment: Thanks fartem, Can you explain brief. And also I wanted to share this file through mail every month on button action.

Comment: In your case, you can track last share time and show a dialog (or any UI element for a user) to request backup sending.